# PDF Not redering in HTML page but giving download dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a webpage in which trying to render pdf using object,
When i run that page on my local machine it renders fine, But when i host it on server, it is not rendering...

1.Mozila Fiefox giving alt path which i have mentioned in alt tag
 2.Chrome giving only download file dialog
 3.Edge renders pdf but taking long time to render.

```
<div class="col-md-12 pdf">
    <object data="./assets/ABC/abc.pdf" type="application/pdf">
        alt : <a href="./assets/ABC/abc.pdf">Download File</a>
    </object>
</div>
```

What is the exact problem???

Comment: Check path for your file.

Comment: File path is correct, because browser giving me download popup